# setting getdate() - 7 hour to zero in a query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query in which I am using a date as a condition (`paiddate`).

I want records from 7 days prior up to today's date.  So, my statement looks like this

```
PaidDate >= GETDATE() - 7
```

I thought I would have it go back to 0 hour of the start day like this

```
PaidDate > DATEADD(d,DATEDIFF(d,7,getdate()),0)
```

However, I get an error that says:

*The conversion of the varchar value '2224560081' overflowed an int column*.

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: So, is paiddate an `INT`?. Is that the only filter you are using?, because `DATEADD(d,DATEDIFF(d,7,getdate()),0)` does work as you intended

Comment: In the SELECT part of your statement you have a varchar that contains the text 2224560081 and it is trying to convert that to an int. You get the same error with this: select cast('2224560081' as int)

Comment: PaidDate is a datetime field.  I am running this in ssms, using a SQL Server 2008 database.

Comment: Ok, so, is that the only filter that you are applying?, are you using some conversions on your `SELECT`?, are you trying to insert values on another table?. I'm asking because you shouldn't get that error because of that `WHERE` condition

Comment: Can you post the full SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, just cast to date:

```
PaidDate >= cast((getdate() - 7) as date)
```

Comment: Why should this work (he doesn't says if he is using SQL Server 2008+) better than what he already has?, his syntax is perfectly fine

Comment: @Lamak Casting to `date` removes the time part of the original `datetime` value. That's what I think the OP is asking for too, based on "go back to 0 hour of the start day".

Comment: @hvd Yes, it does, assuming that he is using SQL Server 2008+, since the `DATE` datatype doesn't exist for previous versions. The point is that the current syntax that op is using `DATEADD(d,DATEDIFF(d,7,getdate()),0)` does exactly what he wants, so the error comes from another part of his query; it won't be solved by doing this

Comment: @Lamak Ah, now I see what you mean, and I agree.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to close this question out. The issue was because there were other filters applied and I had them incorrectly identified (for example client.location in (7001, 7002, 7003). These values should have been strings rather than integers. Thanks to those who responded.